# Excel** Time difference in hours between dates from different sheets

Tags: excel

Hope you can help me with my issue.

I have two tables in two different sheets that are like this:

```
Date Time           |   SESSION_ID  

24/01/2020 10:00    |   100         

24/01/2020 11:00    |   100         

14/03/2020 12:00    |   290         

16/03/2020 13:00    |   254         

16/03/2020 14:00    |   100
```

I need to match the session IDS between the two sheets, and calculate the time difference between the two matches in hours. Only between consecutive matches.

Also I only need to match session ids that are after the datetime of the session id. An example:

*Sheet 1:*

```
Date Time           |   SESSION_ID  

24/01/2020 10:00    |   100         

24/01/2020 11:00    |   100         

14/03/2020 12:00    |   300         

17/03/2020 14:00    |   254         

16/03/2020 15:00    |   200
```

*Sheet 2:* On this sheet, I need to search this sheet's session ids on Sheet 1, and get time difference in hours between the two.

```
Date Time           |   SESSION_ID  | ***Output [hours]***

24/01/2020 09:00    |   100         |   1

24/01/2020 12:00    |   100         |   0 (or "NA")

14/03/2020 12:00    |   290         |   0 (or "NA")   

16/03/2020 13:00    |   254         |   25

16/03/2020 14:00    |   200         |   1
```

Output explanation:
On the first line, the output is 1 hour, because, one hour after this timestamp, 24/01/2020 09:00, there is the same ID on the other sheet.
On the second line, the output is zero hours because after 24/01/2020 12:00, there are no session ids = 100 on the other sheet. 
On the third line, there is a zero because there are no matches.
Forth line, the output is 25 hours, since that's the time difference between the two sessions ids =254.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: @BigBen thank you for your reply, I edited the question, adding an example

Comment: @Cyril Thank you for your reply. I edited the question to have an example of the output. I am looking for a formula. The formats are the same yes. And yes, date type.

Comment: Seems like you could use MINIFS to do this.

Comment: @BigBen seems a nice approach, but I don't have that function :s

Comment: I edited my answer with an equivalent `MIN(IF(...))` array formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MINIFS to do this, something like the following:

```
=MAX(MINIFS($A$2:$A$6,$A$2:$A$6,">"&D2,$B$2:$B$6,E2)-D2,0)
```

- The `MINIFS` gets the minimum corresponding date time that is greater than your lookup date time.
- Then you just subtract the lookup date time.
- The `MAX` returns the `0` as per your requirements (otherwise the `MINIFS(...)-D2` would be negative).

Change the number format of the output column to `[h]`.

If you need the output column to actual number of hours, then just multiply by 24 and don't change the number format.

[image]

If you don't have `MINIFS`, then use the following array formula and confirm it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=MAX(MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$6>D2)*($B$2:$B$6=E2),$A$2:$A$6))-D2,0)
```